# JetBrains WebStorm debugger doesn't work since upgrading for 7.0.1 and 7.0.2

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

An angular project with this structure:

```
project name:
--/app folder
--/app/index.html
```

In directories/settings I set the project name as content source, and `app` folder as resource folder. The URL is set as: `http://localhost:63342/app/index.html`.

I have the chrome plugin installed but when I run the debugger I see "404 page not found" message.

If I set the url to `http://localhost:63342/angular/index.html` (with selecting the index.html file) I do get the page but without any resource,  with this kind of errors (for example, images, templates and the rest).

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:63342/img/home_page_1024.jpg
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

All of them should be under `app` folder but missing in the debug page (the regular page I run works fine.. )

I heard there is some "plugin configuration" to override CORS. But I'm not sure what
another problem is that I need the app to run from `local.mycompany.com` instead of localhost (in my machine it's set up in the hosts file and works fine) but when I try to set the debugger url as `http://local.mycompany.com:63342/angular/index.html` I just get jetbrains 404 page.

Comment: **1)** When using **built-in** simple web server, the URL should be in this format: **`http://localhost:63342/PROJECT_NAME/the_rest_of_path`** (it's generated automatically by IDE when using "Open in Browser" action, BTW). The alternative URL is **`http://PROJECT_NAME:63342/the_rest_of_path`** and `PROJECT_NAME` must point to 127.0.0.1 via your `hosts` file or local DNS server.

Comment: **2)** If you want to use your custom domain (`http://local.mycompany.com`) then you will have to use your own web server (Apache/nginx/IIS etc).

Comment: **3)** *"...I do get the page but without any resource, ..."* When using built-in web server with **first** type of URL (where PROJECT_NAME is part of the path and not domain name) all resources should be referenced in relative format AFAIK (i.e. `img/image.png` instead of `/img/image.png` -- notice the absence of leading slash). With **alternative** URL (PROJECT_NAME as domain name) it should work even with leading slash.